# How to impute default values to Pandas dataframe columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, imputation

Following is the `df.head()` of a DataSet with Date set as index.

```
               Article_ID Country_Code Sold_Units
     Date           
2017-01-01        3576        AT         1
2017-01-02        1579        FR         1
2017-01-02         332        FI         2
2017-01-03        3576        AT         1
2017-01-03         332        SE         1
```

The Country Code has 4 values 'AT, FR, FI, SE'. I want to append these 4 country_codes to every single date if they are not present on those dates and impute their values to 0 in Article_ID and Sold_Units.

The Example output should basically look like this:

```
               Article_ID Country_Code Sold_Units
     Date           
2017-01-01        3576        AT         1
2017-01-01          0         FR         0    # FR FI SE added with 0s.
2017-01-01          0         FI         0
2017-01-01          0         SE         0
2017-01-02          0         AT         0    # AT, SE added
2017-01-02        1579        FR         1
2017-01-02         332        FI         2
2017-01-02          0         SE         0
2017-01-03        3576        AT         1
2017-01-03          0         FR         0    # FR, FI added
2017-01-03          0         FI         0
2017-01-03         332        SE         1
```

How can I add such default values for every country code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions for unique `DatetimeIndex` with `Country_Code` combinations:

Create `MultiIndex` by added `Country_Code` to `DatetimeIndex` with all combinations of unique values of datetimes with codes with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df = (df.set_index('Country_Code', append=True)
        .reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index.unique(), df['Country_Code'].unique()], 
                                            names=['Date','Country_Code']), fill_value=0)
        .reset_index(level=1))
print (df)
           Country_Code  Article_ID  Sold_Units
Date                                           
2017-01-01           AT        3576           1
2017-01-01           FR           0           0
2017-01-01           FI           0           0
2017-01-01           SE           0           0
2017-01-02           AT           0           0
2017-01-02           FR        1579           1
2017-01-02           FI         332           2
2017-01-02           SE           0           0
2017-01-03           AT        3576           1
2017-01-03           FR           0           0
2017-01-03           FI           0           0
2017-01-03           SE         332           1
```

Or use [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with 
[`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = (df.set_index('Country_Code', append=True)
        .unstack(fill_value=0)
        .stack()
        .reset_index(level=1))

print (df)
           Country_Code  Article_ID  Sold_Units
Date                                           
2017-01-01           AT        3576           1
2017-01-01           FI           0           0
2017-01-01           FR           0           0
2017-01-01           SE           0           0
2017-01-02           AT           0           0
2017-01-02           FI         332           2
2017-01-02           FR        1579           1
2017-01-02           SE           0           0
2017-01-03           AT        3576           1
2017-01-03           FI           0           0
2017-01-03           FR           0           0
2017-01-03           SE         332           1
```

Solution for multiple values per datetimes with country codes:

Error means data are like:

```
print (df)
            Article_ID Country_Code  Sold_Units
Date                                           
2017-01-01        3576           AT           1
2017-01-02        1579           FI           1 <-FI
2017-01-02         332           FI           2 <-FI
2017-01-03        3576           AT           1
2017-01-03         332           SE           1
```

---

```
df = (df.groupby(['Date','Country_Code'])
        .sum()
        .unstack(fill_value=0)
        .stack()
        .reset_index(level=1))
print (df)
           Country_Code  Article_ID  Sold_Units
Date                                           
2017-01-01           AT        3576           1
2017-01-01           FI           0           0
2017-01-01           SE           0           0
2017-01-02           AT           0           0
2017-01-02           FI        1911           3
2017-01-02           SE           0           0
2017-01-03           AT        3576           1
2017-01-03           FI           0           0
2017-01-03           SE         332           1
```

Comment: The first option returns: ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!

The Second option returns: ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: @hammeroflight - So it means there are duplicated `Country_Code` for `Date`.

Comment: Yes, there are 4 countries selling a product. Some dates have some countries not selling which need to be imputed with 0s. Every date can have multiple country codes.

Comment: @hammeroflight - I think problem is like for second row change `FR` to `FI` - then get double `FI` for `2017-01-02`.

Comment: The groupby worked perfectly. Thank you, I had been just trying to figure out how to use the unstack with it.

Comment: @hammeroflight - One thing, I want to be fair. Do you need sum `Article_ID` values for 2rd and 3rd data from sample?

Comment: No, your code is exactly what was needed. Perfect use of stack and unstack.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using `pivot_table`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: '2017-01-01', 1: '2017-01-02', 2: '2017-01-02', 3: '2017-01-03', 4: '2017-01-03'},
                   'Article_ID': {0: 3576, 1: 1579, 2: 332, 3: 3576, 4: 332},
                   'Country_Code': {0: 'AT', 1: 'FR', 2: 'FI', 3: 'AT', 4: 'SE'},
                   'Sold_Units': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 1}})

df.set_index("Date",inplace=True)

result = (df.pivot_table(index="Date", columns="Country_Code", values=["Article_ID","Sold_Units"],aggfunc="mean")
         .fillna("0").stack().reset_index(level=1))

print (result)

#
           Country_Code Article_ID Sold_Units
Date                                         
2017-01-01           AT       3576          1
2017-01-01           FI          0          0
2017-01-01           FR          0          0
2017-01-01           SE          0          0
2017-01-02           AT          0          0
2017-01-02           FI        332          2
2017-01-02           FR       1579          1
2017-01-02           SE          0          0
2017-01-03           AT       3576          1
2017-01-03           FI          0          0
2017-01-03           FR          0          0
2017-01-03           SE        332          1
```

Comment: Throws a KeyError: 'Date' as the Date is already set as index.

Comment: Well thats even easier - just remove `index="Date"` part.

Comment: hmmm, maybe the best says about aggregate mean

Comment: `ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index! `

Comment: Umm, now it throws a value error: ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape and the duplicate entries are needed for this problem statement, as each country sells on same dates. So I think we need to go only groupby('Country_Code') in someway.

Comment: Hmm I don't get it. Are the rest of your data vastly different from your sample?

Comment: Not really, it's really the same as shown in the snippet. The Groupby function worked in combination of stack and unstack. Thanks to you I actually learnt something about using pivot table that I was confused about earlier.

Comment: Strange. Does it work if i change to `pivot_table` with `aggfunc="mean"` as suggested by jezrael? Just want to know why it doesn't work :)

Comment: Bloody hell the aggfunc='mean' worked! Now how do I give the two of you the green tick? :P I wasn't using mean, coz I thought it'd alter my values of Article_ID and Sold_Units. You got this one mate. Thank you.